# How to design a solution that needs dynamism using Inheritance

Tags: java, design-patterns, dynamic-inheritance

I have below code/classes/interfaces:

1. An Interface:

   ```
    public interface Animal<A extends Animal<A>>{
    void fight(A otherAnimal);
    }
   ```

2.Tiger class which is implementing Animal

```
    public class Tiger implements Animal{
    @Override
    public void fight(Tiger otherAnimal) {
        System.out.println("Tiger Fights");
    } 
}
```

3. I have a Lion class which also implements Animal

```
  Public class Lion implements Animal{
 @Override
 public void fight(Lion otherAnimal) {
    System.out.println("Lion Fights");
}
```

4. I have a test class which is going to call fight:

   ```
   public class TestClass{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Animal tiger = new Tiger();
      Animal lion = new Lion();
      tiger.fight(lion); 
      } 
   }
   ```

Now when I run the test class the obvious output is "Tiger Fights".

How should I redesign so that when I call fight on tiger with anything other than tiger should call their respective classes.

So in the example above it should invoke lion's fight even if the fight is called on object of tiger.

I need output as "lion fights" even if I am invoking an object of tiger. Meaning actually I want developer to have freedom to pass any type of object to to any class. My expectation is based on type of object the respective overridden method has to be called.

I need this dynamism because there can be N number of different animals (cat, dog, wolf etc) which might get added in near future.

Is it possible to design in such a way that My Animal interface will decide which class to call depending of type of object passed?

Comment: That code does not compile, please check it. I guess you wanted `fight` methods with `Animal` parameters rather than `Tiger`/`Lion` right? However, this is the correct approach for polymorphism - you can have different `fight` methods accepting different kinds of `Animal`s. Is that what you want?

Comment: Are you looking for how to implement double dispatch (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)?

Comment: The second and third lines, beginning with _"How should..."_, and _"So in..."_ respectively, are ininteligible.

Comment: What should the output be?

Comment: @valenterry: I have modified the code now.

Comment: @user61852: I need output as "lion fights" even if I am invoking an object of tiger. Meaning Actually I want developer to have freedom to pass any type of object to to any class. My expectation is based on type of object the respective overriden method has to be called

Comment: You are not getting _"Lion fights"_ because you are calling the `fight` method on an instance of type `Tiger`.

Comment: @user61852 you are absolutely right. But If I want to do it. I can do other way around using instanceOf. But If I do that, every-time I add a new animal class I have to modify each and every animal class to check for this class. How should I do a generalization so that I don't have to modify each class every time when I add a new Animal class.

Comment: @DocBrown I would highly appreciate if you can please give me the solution in java for above problem using double dispatch ?

Comment: @TonyAdityaStark You can have an accept method in `Animal` in which that instance then calls fight on your instance so your Tiger doesn't fight another instance, but that instance fights your Tiger.  However, in this context it doesn't make any sense to do it this way.  Could you be more specific about what you want to use this for?

Comment: @Neil: This was indeed a study exercise and I was asked this question a year back by my mentor. I just want to do so that I can learn. And the approach you said will be indeed helpful. Can we do it in a way as "instance fights with tiger" ? I just need a solution in a Visitor design pattern.

Comment: @TonyAdityaStark Edited answer.  Let me know if this is sufficient.

Comment: I keep reading this and wondering what problem are you trying to solve? The way the question looks now, you are trying to find a problem for a solution.  The "needs dynamism using Visitor Design pattern" looks like you are trying to force it into a particular pattern which often is a less than ideal situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you're setting up `Animal` interface with generics in order to make the `Animal` instance passed to fight as the same as the one implementing `Animal`.  In other words, `Lion` can only fight a `Lion`.  A `Tiger` can only fight a `Tiger`.  From the sounds of it, you want to be able to fight any animal.  If you don't need to use A for any other reason in interface, ditch it.  It isn't helpful.

```
public interface Animal {
  void fight(Animal otherAnimal);
}
```

Second, now that you're receiving an `Animal` instance, you need to know if it is an instance of the very same class implementing `Animal`.

To do this, you could simply write:

```
public class Tiger implements Animal{
    @Override
    public void fight(Animal otherAnimal) {
        if(otherAnimal.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) {
            System.out.println("Two tigers fight");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tiger fights a " + otherAnimal.getClass().getName());
        }
    } 
}
```

This works fine so long as you don't need to know *what* type `otherAnimal` is.  In other words, if you start constructing if.. else lists to cover every possibility, you're doing it wrong.  Tiger should know how it fights other animals, and anything that might change the outcome should be something that all `Animal` instances have.

For instance, if you want to attack "Pokemon" style with each animal having its own health bar, you need not cast it to `Lion` to get the `Lion`'s health points.  You need only create a "getHealthPoints" method in `Animal`.

If you're using Java 8, you can even make use of defaults in your interface and override only if your subclass needs to behave differently:

```
public interface Animal {
  default void fight(Animal otherAnimal) {
     if(otherAnimal.getClass().equals(this.getClass()) {
         System.out.println("Two " + this.getClass().getName() + "s fight");
     } else {
         System.out.println(this.getClass().getName() + " fights a " + otherAnimal.getClass().getName());
     }
  }
}
```

For this particular example, this should be sufficient, though if you're looking for an example of Visitor pattern, [the wikipedia article on Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example) provides a decent explanation.  Note that the structure is more hierarchical and serves primarily for performing an operation on each object in it.  This would be a bit of an overkill for this particular instance, so I won't modify the above example.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a class for code that calls a winner of 2 animals fighting, then the solution is a third class that does that. Imagine you have to write a `compare` method that compares objects of 10 very different classes. Obviously you can't have code doing the comparing spread out all over those 10 classes. It's much cleaner to write a `Comparator` class.

If you are just asking how to write code `x operation y` where you can code `operation` for each `x` and `y` type pair separately then you're looking for dual dispatch, usually implemented by `Visitor` pattern.

Edit: you are also misusing generic types. You are adding generic type of A to whole Animal type just for the target type of fight method. You should add generic type to the method only.

The correct declaration of animal would be:

```
public interface Animal {
    <A extends Animal> void fight(A otherAnimal);
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for.I was unaware this is called Visitor pattern.
I want to implement solution in Visitor pattern.
If you can please help me by elaborating answer by providing the answer with a code snippet for the above problem in Visitor pattern, I would highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

From what you wrote, it is still a little bit unclear what you are after, but I guess when a "Tiger" fights a "Lion", you do not want to have printed "Tiger fights" or "Lions fights", but something like "Tiger fights Lion". And that is nothing for which you need double dispatch or the visitor pattern.

Just separate the "output part" from the "who fights" part:

```
public interface Animal {
   String Race();
   int Strength();
}

public class Tiger implements Animal{
  @Override
  public String Race() {
      return "Tiger";
  } 
  @Override
  public int Strength() {
      return 10;
  }
```

(yes, the `Race` part could be more elegantly implemented by using `this.getClass().getName()`, but this is for demonstration purposes). I have added an additional `Strength` method to make clearer how this works and how to implement actual logic with it. Place the fight method (the output part) somewhere else, and implement it in terms of "Animals":

```
public class Arena {
public void fight(Animal a1, Animal a2) {
    System.out.println(a1.Race() + " fights " + a2.Race());
    if(a1.Strength()>a2.Strength)
    {
         System.out.println(a1.Race() + " wins");
    }
    else if(a1.Strength()<a2.Strength)
    {
         System.out.println(a2.Race() + " wins");
    }
    else
    {
         System.out.println("Tie.");
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add more different animals, without touching any of the existing animal classes or touching the `fight` method.

Comment: Wow.. This is approach is good...I have had spent many hours to find out the approach. I came across a design pattern called "Visitor". I want to implement solution in Visitor pattern. If you can please help me by elaborating answer by providing the answer with a code snippet for the above problem in Visitor pattern, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: @TonyAdityaStark: I doubt the visitor pattern will bring you any further. The topmost rule about patterns is: do not make your problem fit to a pattern when the problem does not match the pattern naturally.